# Open JPA. Can't load data from managed entity

Tags: java, openjpa

I have some scheduler that processes some data
While processing it used reloading:

```
    Set<String> codes = new HashSet<>();
    Entity entity = EntityManager.find(Entity.class, id);
    codes.add(entity.getEntity1().getEntity2().getEntity3().getCode();
```

I have found a NullPointerException in logs which indicates on line 3
Entity (1,2,3) it is mandatory fields. Also I checked it in db, everything is ok.

What could be the reason of NullPointerException?

I use open JPA 2.3.0 (legacy project)

Comment: Looks like no record was found, there `entity` will be a `null` object

Comment: There is null check for entity in real code